# Merging DataFrames on columns that only partially match

Tags: python, pandas

I have two large DataFrames (1m - 5m rows each) with the following structures:

```
DF1                         DF2
    id          value           id    value
0   0000_alpha  100         0   0000  100
1   0000_beta   200         1   0001  200
2   0000_gamma  300         2   0002  300
3   0001_alpha  150         3   0003  400
4   0001_beta   250         4   0004  500
5   0001_gamma  350         5   0005  600
    ....                        ....
```

I would like to add the sum of values from DF1, where the digits of the id are matching but letters are not, to the values in DF2 with the same digits in id. So the final result will be:

```
DF3
    id     value
0   0000   700
1   0001   950
    ....
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to merge the two DataFrames on partially matching ids in an optimal manner (NOTE: the number of digits and letters in each id are NOT consistent. For example: one id might be `0000_alpha`, while another is `4858394_gamma`).

I have the following code, which works, but takes far too long to run, since it is iterating over one of the large DataFrames:

```py
for k,v in DF2.iterrows():
    v['value'] += DF1['value'].loc[DF1.id.str.contains(str(v.id))].sum()
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the above code, perform partial matches in `pd.merge` or `pd.groupby`, or any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.findall` or `str.split` depending on how your `id` column is.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '0000_alpha', 1: '0000_beta', 2: '0000_gamma', 3: '0001_alpha', 4: '0001_beta', 5: '0001_gamma'},
                   'value': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300, 3: 150, 4: 250, 5: 350}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: "0000", 1: "0001", 2: "0002", 3: "0003", 4: "0004", 5: "0005"},
                    'value': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300, 3: 400, 4: 500, 5: 600}})
```

**Method 1**: using `str.findall`:

```
print (pd.merge(df.groupby([df["id"].str.findall("\d+").str[0]]).sum(), df2, on=["id"], how="right").set_index(['id']).sum(axis=1))

#
id
0000    700.0
0001    950.0
0002    300.0
0003    400.0
0004    500.0
0005    600.0
```

**Method 2**: using `str.split`:

```
print (pd.merge(df.groupby([df["id"].str.split("_").str[0]]).sum(), df2, on=["id"], how="right").set_index(['id']).sum(axis=1))

#
id
0000    700.0
0001    950.0
0002    300.0
0003    400.0
0004    500.0
0005    600.0
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the ids are not of equal length. For example: one id could be `0001_alpha`, while another is `459239_alpha`. Just taking the first four characters would produce many partial ids.

Comment: You could have included that in your sample. It is natural to assume the ID are in same format from your data provided.

Comment: I did under 'note', but will add additional clarification to avoid additional confusion.

Comment: I think it is still possible to do with a str search on regex, or simply add a new column in df1 with the extracted result.

Comment: Or you could also use `str.split` and get first element if your id is always *num_alpha* format.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a regex in a .str search. That's what I'll try next.

Comment: @SourPatchAdult I updated my answer with the mentioned methods.

Comment: I ended up using method 2 and it worked as desired. Thanks for the added methods.